# AMPscript Dynamic Date MobilePush Message

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date, mobilepush, attribute

Is it possible to reference a date attribute of a particular push message? As in something like:

```
%%[
VAR @messageCreatedTime
SET @messageCreatedTime = MessageCreatedTime
]%%
Inbox Subject Line: %%=Format(@messageCreatedTime, "MMMM")=%%
```

So that regardless the month, it would always remain the same?

The goal is to be able create a snippet of AMPscript for the subject line that generates the creation or send date(particularly the month but the whole date has it uses too) in the subject line of a push message. The `Now()` function returns the datetime of when the app launches so it does not help us currently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.